# Function with a constant infinite order derivative, infinite final value, 0 initial value, and graph that resembles geometric growth

Tags: derivatives, graphing-functions, infinity

Please forgive my vocabulary & usage because I'm only a math amateur, so I'll try to describe this the best I can.

Does such a function exist that has an infinite order derivative with a constant value, an initial value of 0, and a final value of infinity.

If so, what is it?

I know this is probably an incorrect way to describe a function, but I am unsure how to properly describe this function.

It's graph resembles geometric growth.

[**Data**](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0AuOQpwXi8SHEdDJ2NjE2UzVfTWg5Z3ZkQ3QzTkE3YkE&usp=sharing)

---

Could it look something an infinite number of integrals of $(1+x)^n$?

Comment: What do you mean by 'infinite derivative with a constant value'?

Comment: @T.Bongers Thank you for looking T. Bongers!  I think I mean the infinite order derivative of the function.  Does that make more sense? In other words, the infinity-1 order derivative might be `x`, and the infinity-2 order derivative might be `x^2+x`.  Please bear with me.  I simply don't have the skills.  Thank-you so very much in advance!

Comment: In order I try to understand, could you post the data points since I suppose that you probably want to curve fit the data with a function like the one you try to describe ?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Thank you so much Claude Leibovici!  You are correct.  I will post it as soon as possible.  Please come back and take another look.  Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: @Gracchus. I have problems trying to use and recover your data. As I can percieve them (I am blind), everything seems to move fast. Could you plot Log(Y) as a function of X as well as Log(Y) as a function of Log(X). Tell me if one of these plots looks like a straight line. Thanks.

Comment: I don't think the idea of an "infinite order derivative" is going to be useful, or if it is, it's just going to get you a power series (Taylor or MacLaurin)

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Thank you for looking again Claude Leibovici!  I have edited the data to show those graphs.  Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: @tabstop Thank you tabstop!  Could you please expand in an answer?  That was the best I could come up with after thinking about this myself.  Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: @Gracchus. I really do not see what kind of function could be used for the fit of these data ! What do they represent if I may ask ?

Answer (score 1):

The classic function with all derivatives zero that doesn't stay stuck at zero is $e^{\frac {-1}x}$ near zero but positive, $0$ for $x$ negative.  That doesn't go to infinity for large $x$, but that is easily fixed.  How about $f(x)=xe^{{-1}/x}$ for positive $x$, $0$ for $x \le 0$

Comment: Thank you for trying Ross!  It doesn't seem to grow fast enough.  I edited the link to show a graph.  I apologize for not being clear, but I do not want all derivatives to equal 0; rather, I'd prefer the derivative of the infinite order to be constant.  Are you saying that the only way for the infinite order derivative to be constant is for all derivatives to equal 0?  Thank you so very much in advance!

Comment: You can multiply by any polynomial you want.  I picked $x$ because it is simple and goes to infinity for large $x$.  The derivatives at $0$ will stay zero.  If that's still not fast enough you can multiply by e^(some polynomial).  Basically the $e^{(-1/x)}$ controls the behavior at zero to give zero derivatives.  What happens above is up to you.